# self destruct button in html

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to destroy an html button. If it is clicked because it already served its purpose after clicking.

Comment: I'm not sure it's good usability... of course it depends on what you are doing, but I would make it disabled and change the label to something like "Done"

Comment: The few, memorable times I've encountered this, it was implemented in order to reduce server strain because requests were timing out. Because requests were timing out, when the button was disabled, the only way most people knew how to submit the form a second time was to reload the page and enter all the data in over again. The moral is: fix your server-side script to handle impatience or broken connections!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can disable or hide it. Example:

```
<input type="button" onclick="this.disabled=true;" />
```

However, if you do this to the submit button, it may not work properly. The value for the button will not be included in the form data, so if the server looks for the button data to find out what it was that caused the form to submit, it won't find it.

Comment: But this doesn't happen if you hide the button using display = none.

Comment: @littlegreen: That may be browser dependant, so I wouldn't rely on it. I remember having problems with Netscape not sending data from invisible fields...

Answer (score 12):

You can do so with JavaScript:

```
<button onclick="this.parentNode.removeChild(this)">Label</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, by using JavaScript to set its CSS property "display" to "none".

See also [Seven ways to toggle an element with JavaScript](http://www.dustindiaz.com/seven-togglers/).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do also by

```
<input type="button" onclick="this.style.visibility='hidden';">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="this.style.display = 'none';">
```